# Can I use the Scipy simulated annealing library to solve the traveling salesman problem?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

To solve the traveling salesman problem with simulated annealing, we need to start with an initial solution, a random permutation of the cities. This is the order in which the salesman is supposed to visit them. Then, we switch to a "neighboring solution" by swapping two cities. And then there are details around when to switch to the neighboring solution, etc.

I could implement all of this from scratch. But I wanted to see if I could use the inbuilt Scipy annealing solver. Looking at the documentation, looks like the [old anneal method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html) has been deprecated. The new methods that is supposed to have replaced it is [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping). But looking through the documentation and source code, it seems these are more towards optimizing a function of some array where any float values of that array are permissible (and then there are local and global optima). That's what all the examples in the documentation or code comments are geared towards. I can't imagine how I would use any of these inbuilt routines to solve the famous traveling salesman problem itself since the array there is a permutation array. If you just perturb its values by some floating point numbers, you won't get a valid solution.

So, the conclusion seems to be that those standard routines are inapplicable on a combinatorial optimization problem like the traveling salesman? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Meta-heuristics find good solutions. They don't really solve problems to proven optimality. A real TSP solver is Concorde.

Comment: Not too long ago someone else was trying to apply the `scipy` `dual_annealing` function to TSP.  He'd already written his own simulated annealing solver.  I had to point out that just because they both use "annealing" the problem spaces have nothing in common.  He'd have to still use his own code to generate different combinations.  The scipy optimize methods tweak an array of float values (an `Rn` space).  In general `numpy/scipy` isn't that great for OR style search problems.